# Can not load the qt platform plugin windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, deployment

When I compile the project then work  in my computer there is no error. But Whenever I run the project in another computer, occurred the error

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put `qwindows.dll` in a directory named `platforms` alongside the executable. Try to deploy your application using [The Windows Deployment Tool](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html#the-windows-deployment-tool) which could be found in `QTDIR/bin/windeployqt.exe`. It automatically puts all necessary files in your application directory.

Open your command prompt and add the path to your Qt directory and it's `bin` folder to the `PATH` variable like :

```
set PATH= path\to\Qt\bin
```

Next run the windows deployment tool with your application path as the argument:

```
windeployqt.exe  <path-to-app-binary>
```

Comment: Are you sure you elaborated windeployqt properly? Did it produce any errors or warnings?

Comment: Did you set the path to Qt bin directory properly? What did you exactly set? Also are you sure that you run `windeployqt.exe` from its directory?

Comment: This project work well in my computer. But when I run exe another computer It give me this error